# Facebook API silent login

Tags: api, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk, silent

I am trying to use facebook API to provide a silent login feature.

Application has to login onto facebook without prompting for user name and password. The authentication can be done through the application.

I want to know whether this can be done using the facebook API. I'd also want to know whether some paid facility is available to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not support silent login. Facebook only permits authorization through its own servers and browser windows, because it does not trust third party developers to handle their passwords.
You will have to authenticate once, then get an access token, and you can keep using the access token to auto login the user, until it expires. Have a look here or search google on "how to get Facebook access token c#"

[Auto Facebook OAuth from ASP.NET C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494865/auto-facebook-oauth-from-asp-net-c-sharp)

Comment: speaking of "does not trust third party developers to handle their passwords", is there any way to grant access to trusted third party developers to handle the encrypted passwords and implement a silent login procedure without alerting users with login dialog boxes?