# Connecting FB accounts with accounts on my website for direct login

Tags: asp.net, facebook

Scenario here is:

Any browser, user already logged in to his Facebook account (say browser Tab no.1).
Same browser, Tab no.2, user visits my website (he has already registered to my website using his Facebook account, as I store his Facebook ID).
Upon his visit to my website home page, he has logged in to my website even though he has only logged in to Facebook, but never visited my website and clicked on the Login button).
how can i enable this functionality in asp.net?

Comment: I believe this is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494865/auto-facebook-oauth-from-asp-net-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a users table in your database, which contains:

```
UserID, UserName, UserEmail, UserPassword
```

When a user registers on your site without facebook you create a new entry in users table.

For facebook functionality you need to modify the users table:

```
UserID, UserName, UserEmail, UserPassword, UserFacebookID
```

When a user logs in with facebook you get his **{facebook id}** and **{facebook email}**.

If there is already a user in the database with the current **{facebook id}** you know he is a registered user and log him in.

If not, then it's the first time the user uses facebook log in, and you must check if there is a matching email in your database:

```
if({facebook email} is in users table)
{
     update users table, set UserFacebookID = {facebook id}
}
else
{
     create a new user in users table
}
```

I currently work at a Web Agency and that's basically what we've done for Facebook Connect situations. Hope this helps.

Library: [Facebook C# SDK](http://csharpsdk.org/).